# Compare timestamp with date in php

Tags: php

i have this code which permits me to retrieve all the information in which the timestamp regarding that information is equal to another date.

Here is the code:

```
$information="SELECT * FROM scheda_anagrafica WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME('time_inserted','%d-%m-%Y') = '" . $giorno_selcted. "'
 "; 
$result1 = mysql_query($information) or die (mysql_error());
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    echo $row['information1'];

}
```

giorno_selected prints something like: 25-09-2012
What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please explain it bit more?

Comment: what is the content of $giorno_selcted

Comment: Yes sure, so i have a field in the database which is a timstamp, and the current date i.e ; let's suppose the timestamp gives me 23-09-2012 12:23:45 and the date variable gives me 23-09-2012, i need to check if the timestamp and date are equal, but i need to do that in the query.

Comment: $giorno_selected prints out a date, something like 12-09-2012

Comment: off topic, but it's worth mentioning that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` funcs are considered obsolete. PHP manual **strongly** recommends switching to `mysqli_xxx()` or PDO library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you should not use mysql functions on the left hand side of a operator in a where clause. this way mysql needs to read the complete table on disk to compute the value to compare with instead of optimizing the query for speed and resource usage (IO, cpu).

from your question and comments i understand, that you are querying the database for rows which have the same day as the string in your `$giorno_selected` represents. so you need to find all rows with timestamps between 0:00 and 23:59 on that specific day:

```
$giorno_timestamp_start = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $giorno_selected)->getTimestamp();
$giorno_timestamp_end = $giorno_timestamp_start + 86399; //add almost all seconds per day onto the start timestamp

$information="SELECT * FROM scheda_anagrafica WHERE time_inserted BETWEEN " . $giorno_timestamp_start. " AND ". $giorno_timestamp_end; 
$result1 = mysql_query($information) or die (mysql_error());
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    echo $row['information1'];

}
```

this works if your `time_inserted` column is of type `integer` and holds unix_timestampds.
if it is of type `datetime` or `timestamp` you need to modify the query like this:

```
$information="SELECT * FROM scheda_anagrafica WHERE time_inserted BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $giorno_timestamp_start. ") AND FROM_UNIXTIME(". $giorno_timestamp_end .")";
```

Comment: Hey thanks, well i didn't understand this quite well, could you please tell me,how can i convert a timestamp using maybe the date function into d-m-Y? so i can immediately compare them in the query?
I did it using date function but it gives me a strange date, like 1970-01-01

Comment: in order to compare something you need a make sure its of the same type. otherwise you would compare apples with oranges. so, to compare a string holding something like `23-09-2012` with an integer in your database like `1348674213` you need to convert the string into a integer representing the same value. thats what the `date_create_from_format()` function does.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that i need to make the comparison right from the query, i mean i'd need to use something like this : WHERE date('d-m-Y',strtotime('time_inserted')='26-09-2012' where time_inserted is the field...

Comment: Let me explain please, i have some forms submitted and in the database fields, for each submission i have the respective timestamp, and i need to retrieve all form information of today's date, but to do that i need a where in the sql query.. i don't know if i explained myself the correct way...

Comment: i understand you fully and thats exactly what my solution does provide. all you need to know is which type the timestamp column in your table has, integer or datetime.

Comment: yes sure, well i'll give a try to your code here.. my timestamp column is of type timestamp..